# Sony smartwatch 2 without notification extension

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

At the moment I want to extend one of my application to get the notifications on wearable as well.
I've noticed that on sony smartwatch 2 I don't receive any notification by default.. and I've searched a bit, and it seems that sony has a different sdk for notifications.

My question is: 
**Is it possible to make the smartwatch work with default api from google instead of sony sdk?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sony smartwatch2 **doesn't run Android Wear**.

Then you can't use the Android Wear API.